# Bootstrap Modal PHP submission

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a site, and having never done something like this, I am unsure how to proceed with PHP. I am working with bootstrap and looking to send an email based on a modal. My HTML looks like

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialoge">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                        <h4>Plan your Party!</h4>

                    </div>

                    <form class="name" name="contact">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Full Name">
                                </div>l

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" style="resize: vertical;" required="required" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i> Submit</button>

                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So I am just wondering if anyone could give me some pointers to make this form actually send the email. I am looking to learn and willing to try anything. Thanks in advance, help and constructful criticism appreciated. Also, how would I approach adding a confirmation that the message has been sent?

Thanks, John.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php", // 
                data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg)
                    $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the script I tried to add  to call the php:

```
<?php

$myemail = 'myemail@myemail.ca';


if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$name."<br>";   
echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>"; 
echo "<stong>Message:</strong> ".$message."<br>";


$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

And I mean I am sure there is something I am missing, or some simple fix, this is all just so new to me.

Comment: You have two choices to do this. 1) Use `form action='sendmail.php'` and sendmail.php will be the PHP page  which will actually send the mail. This is to be use if you are OK with page reload. 2) Use AJAX to POST all data to a PHP page and send mail. This is to be used if you don't want the page to reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the edits for you:

1) You have two forms in the modal and none of them having closing form tag. Remove `<form class="form-horizontal">` form and change your other form to `<form class="contact">`

2) Give closing form tag.

3) Change submit button to `<button class="btn btn-success" id="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i> Submit</button>`

4) Also check updated AJAX code and PHP code.

Hope this should help you..

**HTML**

```
<div id="thanks"> </div>
<p>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#contact" 
    class="btn btn-primary">Contact us</a>
</p>
<!-- model content --> 
<div class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; " id="contact" > 
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4>Plan your Party!</h4>
            </div>
            <form class="contact">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" style="resize: vertical;" required="required" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i> Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg);
                    $("#contact").modal('hide'); 
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
    $myemail = 'myemail@myemail.ca';
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
    {
        $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

        $msg_success = "";
        $msg_fail = "Error sending mail.";
        $msg_success .= "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
        $msg_success .= "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$name."<br>";   
        $msg_success .= "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>"; 
        $msg_success .= "<stong>Message:</strong> ".$message."<br>";

        $to = $myemail;
        $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
        " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
        "Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
        $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

        if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers))
            echo $msg_success;
        else
            echo $msg_fail;
    }
    else
        echo "Input parameters missing";
?>
```

Comment: I tried adding the changes,  but see something I missed. The issue I was having is the only thing it wouldn't do is follow the post. I see a change that I missed and I will try tonight. I thank you kindly for all your help thus far though.

Answer (score 0):

In `form` tag include `action` attribute to point any PHP page, from there you can send emails...

Comment: I have tried adding these actions, though I just end up messing up the entirety of my modal. I have never worked with PHP so this really is a first project here for me. Just something I have been tinkering at and would truly like to learn.

Comment: 'I have tried adding these actions, though I just end up messing up the entirety of my modal.' => will you add your action page code here also, so that we can help you out of the messing things.

Comment: Yeah you have to provide your action file code, how can we know what you want to send through mail function.. for now I can just show sample mail function example:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/sending-email-from-site/using-the-php-mail-function-to-send-emails